# How to make an SSL connection to MySQL using MariaDB Connector/J?

Tags: java, mysql, security, ssl, mariadb

I'm using MySQL 5.7.10 with SSL enabled and certificates generated as per [these instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html). My Java 7 application uses a [MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/) and SSL is enabled in the JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://dbservername:3306/dbname?useSSL=true&trustServerCertificate=false
```

But the connection fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
...
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of
64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
```

According to [this blog post](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2015/08/11/ssltls-connections-to-recent-mysql-servers-in-java/), the problem could be resolved by:

1. Upgrading to Java 8 (or higher).
2. Downgrading to MySQL 5.7.5 (or lower).
3. Excluding Diffie-Hellman (DH) ciphers.

(1) isn't an option on the project I'm working on. (2) seems restrictive and would prevent access to future MySQL improvements. (3) seems the most promising: I've verified it does work with [MySQL connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) but unfortunately its GPL license prevents me from being able to use it on my project.

Does MariaDB Connector/J have an equivalent property to `enabledSSLCipherSuites` or is there any other way to prevent it from using DH ciphers when connecting?

Comment: Whereas MySQL Connector/J calls [`javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(String[] suites)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setEnabledCipherSuites(java.lang.String[])) in [com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(MysqlIO mysqlIO)](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/ExportControlled.java#L146), sadly MariaDB Connector/J [does not](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mariadb/jdbc/internal/protocol/AbstractConnectProtocol.java#L431-L437).

Comment: Thanks - very nicely pinpointed! Guess this is pointing towards the option of updating the open source code to include this...

Comment: ...or filing a bug report and waiting for the MariaDB team to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requested feature options have now been implemented in MariaDB Connector/J version 1.5.0-RC:

> **enabledSslProtocolSuites**  Force TLS/SSL protocol to a specific set of
>   TLS versions (comma separated list).  Example : "TLSv1, TLSv1.1,
>   TLSv1.2" Default: TLSv1, TLSv1.1. Since 1.5.0
>
> **enabledSslCipherSuites**    Force TLS/SSL cipher (comma separated list).
>   Example : "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" Default: use JRE ciphers. Since
>   1.5.0

(See the comments below the question, the [release notes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-connector-j-150-release-notes/) and [this Jira ticket](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-249).)