"The server selected protocol version TLS11 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]"
I'm trying to connect to an old MariaDB instance with schemacrawler and I get this error The server selected protocol version TLS11 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]
I tried removing TLSv1.1 from jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in runtime\conf\security\java.security but it doesn't seem to change anything.
Another suggestion is to pass ‑Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.1" to the java command line, but I didn't find how to pass additional Java options.
Not sure if it's relevant: I installed schemacrawler using scoop.
UPDATE: I'm now using the docker image with a custom schemacrawler.sh so that I can tweak java options, but I still can't get it to work.
I've tried adding -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.1" -> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
This makes sense because TLS 1.1 is disabled by default, so to re-enable it (considering i can't edit java.security in Docker), I created a file enableLegacyTLS.security as follows (just removed TLS1 from the same property in java.security):
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, DTLSv1.0, RC4, DES, \
    MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

and added -Djava.security.properties=enableLegacyTLS.security to the command line. Now I get javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS11 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12] which doesn't make sense because I'm explicitly telling Java to use TLS 1.1!
At this point I don't know what else I can try...
UPDATE 2: here goes the full error log with stack traces:
SEVERE: Could not connect to <jdbc:mysql://rct-clmadfundchanneldb:3306/>, for <user 'userAppliPHP'>, with properties <{}>
us.fatehi.utility.SQLRuntimeException: Could not connect to <jdbc:mysql://rct-clmadfundchanneldb:3306/>, for <user 'userAppliPHP'>, with properties <{}>
        at us.fatehi.utility.datasource.AbstractDatabaseConnectionSource.getConnection(AbstractDatabaseConnectionSource.java:126)
        at us.fatehi.utility.datasource.SimpleDatabaseConnectionSource.get(SimpleDatabaseConnectionSource.java:113)
        at us.fatehi.utility.datasource.SimpleDatabaseConnectionSource.get(SimpleDatabaseConnectionSource.java:49)
        at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.command.ConnectCommand.loadSchemaRetrievalOptionsBuilder(ConnectCommand.java:180)
        at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.command.ConnectCommand.run(ConnectCommand.java:124)
        at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.executeCommandLine(SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.java:101)
        at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.execute(SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.java:73)
        at schemacrawler.Main.main(Main.java:76)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:165)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:55)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:845)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:420)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:238)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:180)
        at us.fatehi.utility.datasource.AbstractDatabaseConnectionSource.getConnection(AbstractDatabaseConnectionSource.java:121)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:52)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:95)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:140)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:156)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:367)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:198)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1336)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:153)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:969)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS11 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:347)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:303)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:294)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.onServerHello(ServerHello.java:960)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.consume(ServerHello.java:882)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1511)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:206)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:183)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:358)
        ... 16 more


How do you run it?

It may help if you post full stacktrace of errors you are getting.

Stack trace added to OP

Edit .cmd or .sh files you run.
Add you paremeters right after java.

Yes that would be the obvious way, but there's no .cmd or .sh, scoop installs a binary SchemaCrawler.exe

I doubt you can do anything then. Except install it differently.

I'm using docker now so I can pass Java options, but I'm still stuck (see update in my original post)

@OlivierGérardin Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394016/how-to-make-an-ssl-connection-to-mysql-using-mariadb-connector-j
Since SchemaCrawler uses the mariadb-connector-j JDBC driver, you should be able to pass a "--url" connection string instead of the host, port and server.

Thank you @SualehFatehi, I should have stated that I was using the MySQL driver, I didn't realize that I could use the MariaDB driver by passing an URL...
